# Using @Value annotation to Inject single property

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have a class in which i want only one property to  be injected from the properties file.
The class is like this:

```
@Getter
public class BatchContext {

    private final String city;
    private final String channel;

    @Value("${table.url: https://www.someurl.com}")
    private final String url;

    @Builder
    public BatchContext(String city, String channel, @Value("${table.url:https://www.someurl.com}") String url) {
        this.city = city;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

I wanted to just pass country and segment to the BatchContext and wanted to load url from the properties file but the url turns out to be null, whats the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Why do you have the url in there, table.url should be the key, delete the rest. Also it is sufficient to use @Value for one time, don't use for the function parameter part, you do not need it in the constructor since it will already be assigned via Value annotation.

Comment: Hi, Can you kindly give me some example. If i don't add url in constructor then it says that i should a url to the constructor as its not initialized, but if i add it to the constructor then the call should provide the value for that which takes away the whole purpose of the @Value. i want the url value to be injected from the properties file without the caller to provide that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Madu, it seems your problem is related just to your class.
It is not a Bean for Spring context, then your @Value cannot be injected by Spring.

Try setting your class as an object managed by Spring, e.g. @Component:

```
@Component
public class BatchContext {...
}
```

Comment: So do you mean that @Value annotation only work for spring manged classes?

Comment: That's it, Madu! :)